# TitanFactory static build method

Tags: java, titan

I'm new to Java and playing with [Titan DB](http://thinkaurelius.github.io/titan/).

Per the documentation of the [Cassandra backend](http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/current/cassandra.html), `TitanFactory` has a static method `build()`:

```
TitanGraph g = TitanFactory.build()
    .set("storage.backend","cassandra")
    .set("storage.hostname","127.0.0.1")
    .open();
```

However, when looking at [the source](https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/blob/1bf93aa2124c7c1ab9ef6e672140a9e30587b1fa/titan-core/src/main/java/com/thinkaurelius/titan/core/TitanFactory.java), it only seems to have an overloaded `open()` method:

```
package com.thinkaurelius.titan.core;

import com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.configuration.GraphDatabaseConfiguration;
import com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.database.StandardTitanGraph;
import org.apache.commons.configuration.Configuration;   
import java.io.File;

public class TitanFactory {

    public static TitanGraph open(String directoryOrConfigFile) {
        return open(GraphDatabaseConfiguration.getConfiguration(new File(directoryOrConfigFile)));
    }

    public static TitanGraph open(Configuration configuration) {
        return new StandardTitanGraph(new GraphDatabaseConfiguration(configuration));
    }

}
```

I thought maybe the version that's up on GitHub is newer than the build I have, but I've got the latest version and GitHub says the file was last modified in May. So I'm thinking I've got to be missing something. `TitanFactory.build()` does, indeed, work. It returns a `TitanFactory` `Builder`. So, where does `build` come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MVN Repository shows the library at [version 0.5.1](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.thinkaurelius.titan/titan-core/0.5.1). The code you download with the maven dependency contains a `TitanFactory#build()` method.

I'm not sure which git branch contains the most up to date code (doesn't seem like `master`), but [this one](https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/blob/titan-0.5.0-M2-tmp/titan-core/src/main/java/com/thinkaurelius/titan/core/TitanFactory.java) seems promising.